# Cepstrum deconvolution Matlab code

Tags: matlab, filter, complex-numbers

I have a little code, that should implement cepstrum deconvolution for minimum phase FIR filter design, but being nonmatlab guy I'm struggling with understanding it. Can someone help?

```
wn = [ones(1,m)
      2*ones((n+odd)/2-1,m)
      ones(1-rem(n,2),m) 
      zeros((n+od d)/2-1,m)];
y = real(ifft(exp(fft(wn.*real(ifft(log(abs(fft(x)))))))));
```

Mainly I don't understand the first line, ".*" symbol in second line and also probably at some point there should be conversion from real to complex domain in the second line, but I have no idea where. Any ideas?

Comment: The `.*` operator means element-wise multiplication. `*` alone would mean matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

- In the first line you are constructing the matrix `wn` row by row.
- `.*` operator means element-wise multiplication. `*` alone would mean matrix multiplication.
  In fact you should pay attention to the size of `x` and `wn` which must be the same for the element-wise multiplication to have sense.
- actually there isn't any conversion from real to complex in the second line. There are the functions `log`, `fft`, `ifft` that may return complex values depending on the input.

You can access the Matlab help by the commands `help` or `doc` (for example `doc ones` should produce the documentation of the `ones` function - this produce a matrix filled with ones of the size specified by it's arguments).

To quickly summon the help when you're inspecting some code you can use Matlab's inline help by pressing the button <kbd>F1</kbd> when the cursor is at the end of a function name (just before the parenthesis).